# How to fetch multiple private registries from AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr-public/describe-registries.html lists multiple registries for a public ECR registry (i.e. ecr-public). How to do the same for private registries

AWS ECR CLI **doesn't** mention **describe-registries** in the following section and the question is how to fetch multiple private registries if configured
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each private registry is belong to its AWS account.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html

So you can only use [describe-registry](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/describe-registry.html) for your account.

Comment: If there is more than one private registry bound to the same AWS account, how do I list only the private registries alone

Comment: @Rpj as far as I know, it is not possible

Comment: I am pretty sure customers have such configuration, the CLI not supporting this for private registries seems to be a gap

Comment: @Rpj can you please explain this: `I am pretty sure customers have such configuration`, do you have any source about it?

Comment: Amazon ECR seems to allow only creation of a single private registry and its tied to a  AWS account, hence describe-registry is allowed instead of describe-registries.

Comment: @Rpj yes, this is what I mean